# how to assign the output of a string separated by column to a variable in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a PowerShell script to get the required contents from a log/text file. The file looks like below:

```
node1 : data1
node2 : data2
Administrators : Data is Not Available at this moment
desiredouput : data3
format : format-type
node1 : data4
node2 : data5
Administrators : user1, user2, user3, user4, user5, user6
desiredoutput : data6
format : format-type
node1 : data7
node2 : data8
Administrators : user1, user2, user3, user4, user5, user6, user7, user8, user9, user10, user11, 
user12, user13, user14, user15, user16, user17, user18, user19, user20
desiredoutput : data9
format : format-type
.....
the sequence continues
.....
```

As you can see after every five lines, the new data will be displayed to the same variable on the left.

I want to fetch the data after **:** in each and every line and assign that to a variable. Here is the code I am writing:

```
        $deliverycontent = @()
        $filecontent = Get-Content -Path <path to the text file>
        $datacount = $filecontent.Length
        for ($i=0; $i -lt $datacount; $i+=5)
        {
            $temp = "" |select Header1, Header2, Header3, Header4, Header5
            $temp.Header1 = ($filecontent[$i]).Split(":")[1]
            $temp.Header2 = ($filecontent[$i+1]).Split(":")[1]
            $temp.Header3 = ($filecontent[$i+2]).Split(":")[1]
            $temp.Header4 = ($filecontent[$i+3]).Split(":")[1]
            $temp.Header5 = ($filecontent[$i+4]).Split(":")[1]
            $deliverycontent += $temp
        }
```

while running the above script, I am seeing the data is not properly assigned especially for the output of the **administrators** because the output of the administrators is a huge string and it is printing the output in the next line instead in a single line in the text file so the powershell output is not displaying as expected. How can I assign the entire string of the administrators to a single variable even it is printed in the next lines as per the loop condition provided.

The desired output is:

```
Header1: data1
Header2: data2
Header3 : Data is Not Available at this moment
Header4: data3
Header5: format-type

Header1: data4
Header2: data5
Header3 : user1, user2, user3, user4, user5, user6
Header4: data6
Header5: format-type

Header1: data7
Header2: data8
Header3 : user1, user2, user3, user4, user5, user6, user7, user8, user9, user10, user11, user12,
user13, user14, user15, user16, user17, user18, user19, user20                         
Header4: data6
Header5: format-type
....

<the sequence follows>
....

How can I achieve this?
```

Comment: It's not clear if the file content on the `Administrators` line have it's contents on a new line or it's just the PS host displaying it like that. If you open the file on notepad **without word wrapping**, is it all on one line or does it shows in multiple lines?

Answer (score 2):

The multi-line Administrator value is actually relatively easy to fix if things are formatted as you suggest without variance. What you can do is read in everything as a multi-line string (by adding the `-raw` parameter to your `Get-Content` command). Then remove any New Line/Carriage Return characters that are not followed by `Something :` (a word followed by a space and a colon). You can do that with a RegEx Negative Lookahead. Then just split it all on the remaining new lines and you'll end up with a file that will work with the rest of your script just fine.

```
    $deliverycontent = @()
    $filecontent = Get-Content -Path <path to the text file> -raw
    $filecontent = $filecontent -replace '[\r\n]+(?!\w+ :)' -split '[\r\n]+'
    $datacount = $filecontent.Length
    $deliverycontent = for ($i=0; $i -lt $datacount; $i+=5)
    {
        $temp = "" |select Header1, Header2, Header3, Header4, Header5
        $temp.Header1 = ($filecontent[$i]).Split(":")[1]
        $temp.Header2 = ($filecontent[$i+1]).Split(":")[1]
        $temp.Header3 = ($filecontent[$i+2]).Split(":")[1]
        $temp.Header4 = ($filecontent[$i+3]).Split(":")[1]
        $temp.Header5 = ($filecontent[$i+4]).Split(":")[1]
        $temp
    }
```

I also changed how `$deliverycontent` collects data so that it isn't constantly rebuilding the array, which is what happens when you do `$deliverycontent += $temp`.

Comment: Very clever solution!

Answer (score 1):

Once the offending new line/carriage return is removed as [TheMadTechnician](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3245749/themadtechnician) [demonstrates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68198265/4085331), you have a few options from there.

If you're using powershell core you can make use of the `ConvertFrom-StringData`'s `-Delimiter` parameter

```
$text = Get-Content $datafile -Raw

$text -replace '[\r\n]+(?!\w+ :)' -split '(?=node1)' | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]$($_ | ConvertFrom-StringData -Delimiter :)
}
```

If you care about the order of the properties, you can use an ordered hashtable.

```
$text -replace '[\r\n]+(?!\w+ :)' -split '(?=node1)' | ForEach-Object {
    $ht = [ordered]@{}
    $_ -split '\r?\n' | Foreach-Object {$ht += $_ | ConvertFrom-StringData -Delimiter :}
    [PSCustomObject]$ht
}
```

Powershell 5.1 you'll need to replace the colon with equals as `ConvertFrom-StringData` doesn't have `-Delimiter`

```
$text = Get-Content $datafile -Raw

$text -replace '[\r\n]+(?!\w+ :)' -replace ':','=' -split '(?=node1)' | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]$($_ | ConvertFrom-StringData)
}
```

Again, to maintain property order.

```
$text -replace '[\r\n]+(?!\w+ :)' -replace ':','=' -split '(?=node1)' | ForEach-Object {
    $ht = [ordered]@{}
    $_ -split '\r?\n' | Foreach-Object {$ht += $_ | ConvertFrom-StringData}
    [PSCustomObject]$ht
}
```